# Передача переменных и использования их (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу передать переменные (Swt, Srt) из формы Settings в Main, и использовать их. Проблема в том что при запуске программы WorkDelay и RecreationDelay создаются пустыми и не изменяются в дальнейшим.

```
public static int Swt, Srt;
public TimeSpan WorkDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt); //Work time in minutes
public TimeSpan WorkDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt); //Work time in minutes
```

Форма Main

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private DateTime _globalTimeDate;

    public static int Swt, Srt;

    private DateTime _workExpiry;
    public TimeSpan WorkDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt); //Work time in minutes

    private DateTime _recreationExpiry;
    public TimeSpan RecreationDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Srt); // Recreation time in minutes

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        stop.Enabled = false;

        global.Text = @"Stoped";
        work.Text = @"Stoped";
        recreation.Text = @"Stoped";
    }

    private void globalTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks - _globalTimeDate.Ticks;
        DateTime stopWatch = new DateTime();
        stopWatch = stopWatch.AddTicks(tick);
        global.Text = $@"{stopWatch:HH:mm:ss}";
    }

    private void workTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan remaining = _workExpiry - DateTime.Now;
        work.Text = remaining.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");

        if (work.Text == @"00:00:00")
        {
            workTimer.Stop();
            work.Text = @"Stoped, start recreation";

            _recreationExpiry = DateTime.Now.Add(RecreationDelay);
            recreationTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void recreationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan remaining = _recreationExpiry - DateTime.Now;
        recreation.Text = remaining.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");

        if (recreation.Text == @"00:00:00")
        {
            recreationTimer.Stop();
            recreation.Text = @"Stoped, strart work";

            _workExpiry = DateTime.Now.Add(WorkDelay);
            workTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _globalTimeDate = DateTime.Now;
        _workExpiry = DateTime.Now.Add(WorkDelay);

        globalTimer.Start();
        workTimer.Start();

        start.Enabled = false;
        stop.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        globalTimer.Stop();
        workTimer.Stop();
        recreationTimer.Stop();

        work.Text = @"Stoped";
        recreation.Text = @"Stoped";

        stop.Enabled = false;
        start.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        globalTimer.Stop();
        workTimer.Stop();
        recreationTimer.Stop();

        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void settingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.Show();
    }
}
}
```

Форма Settings

```
public partial class Settings : Form
{

    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Main.Swt = (int) Convert.ToDouble(textBoxW.Text.Replace(',', '.'));
            Main.Srt = (int) Convert.ToDouble(textBoxR.Text.Replace(',', '.'));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        Close();
    }

    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Swt = 0;
        Main.Srt = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте поля `...Delay` свойствами и вычисляйте их значения при обращении к этим свойствам. Это решит вопрос - "не изменяются в дальнейшем".

```
public TimeSpan WorkDelay { get { return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt); } }
```

В C# 6 (экономим на чернилах для фигурных скобок):

```
public TimeSpan WorkDelay => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt);
```

По поводу "создаются пустыми". Это происходит потому, что начальные значения `Swt` и `Srt` - нули. Присваивайте им какие-нибудь ненулевые значения:

```
public static int Swt = 5;
public static int Srt = 5;
```

P.S.

Вопрос: почему `Swt` и `Srt` - статические, а `WorkDelay` и `RecreationDelay` - поля объекта? Подумайте.

Comment: Спасибо, но я нашел ещё одни вариант:
`public TimeSpan WorkDelay => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Swt);`
Есть ли разница?

Comment: Это то же самое, только с использованием синтаксиса C# 6. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6 Разницы нет.